# why image is not display in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I make a simple demo in angular js to call service .Actually I am not able to display my image in my list .
First check my web service url

- http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/feeds/newsdefaultfeeds.cms?feedtype=sjson
- I call web service using display web security like that **on macc**
  **/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access --user-data-dir=~/chrome-test/ spec/runner.h**tml

**on desktop :**
--disable -websecurity

- I am able to call service but my image is not display on list here is my code on code pen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdPoYN

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="d in data">

    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
        <img src={{d.image.Thumb}}>
        <h2>{{d.HeadLine}}</h2>
        <p>{{d.DateLine}}</p>
    </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: what is the URL of image that you are trying, is it from same domain or from different domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc):

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.

```
<img ng-src={{d.image.Thumb}}>
//   ^^^
```

Comment: Docs :- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc. Kudos !!. You beat me by 20 sec :P. I deleted my anser :P

Comment: still no image display usng your solution

Comment: actually I display my security of chorme .first you disable the web sercuity then check

Comment: use this --disable-web-security in chrome property

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/593726/is-it-possible-to-run-chrome-with-and-without-web-security-at-the-same-time  ...check this

Comment: add this in your chorme browser https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81052/discussion-between-tushar-and-user944513).

Answer (score 0):

Replace with this

```
                   <img ng-src="d.image.Thumb">
```

Comment: This is wrong. Text must be placed in double braces like `{{d.image.Thumb}}`

Comment: No need of double curly braces if ur using 'ng-src'